# Purpose and functionality of Method vs function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, constructor

I am trying to understand what is the difference between creating a method inside a class and creating a function. Both gives same output. Pls provide clarity

```
class Point:
    """ Create a new Point, at coordinates x, y """

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, z=0):
        """ Create a new point at x, y """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = ((self.x ** 2) + (self.y ** 2)) ** 0.5
```

and this function:

```
def distance(x,y):
    z=((x ** 2) + (y ** 2)) ** 0.5
    return z
```

both looks same to me

```
p = Point(3,4)
p.x, p.y, p.z
```

output:
(3, 4, 5.0)

and

```
distance(3,4)
```

output: 5.0

Comment: why do you supply a `z` to your point class that you never use?

Comment: the difference is that the `Point` class stores the x and y as well - your distance function does not. Beside that the question is kindof unclear. You use classes to store data and provide functionality - you use functions to provide functionality - a funciton like yours does not capture state.

Comment: Check out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-method-and-function-in-python#:~:text=A%20method%20in%20python%20is,is%20contained%20within%20the%20class.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the `self` reference - the class instance has access to its own local variables and its methods. In this small example there isn't any need for a class. The function returns a `tuple` object much like the `Point` object you created. There is a rule: If a class has two methods and one of them is `__init__`, you shouldn't have a class. In your case, you didn't even reach the two method bar. (That rule is somewhat tongue-in-cheek but applies most of the time).

The usefulness of classes is when you have multiple methods that naturally share a set of data and you want to keep them together. Or if you have different types of objects that share common functionality and you want them to look the same externally.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly the same.

Some differences:

- The function is available to be used outside the class.
- If you include the calculation in the **init** constructor, the value is saved as an attribute of the class. It will not be recalculated every time you want to see the value.

Answer (score 1):

With a class you should preferably do something like that :

```
class Point:
    """ Create a new Point, at coordinates x, y """

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        """ Create a new point at x, y """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
   
    def distance(self):
        self.z = ((self.x ** 2) + (self.y ** 2)) ** 0.5
        return self.z

p = Point(3, 4)
print(p.distance())
```

The main advantage is to avoid the need of passing parameters to the method while they are required for a function

Answer (score 0):

Here is the gist of it.  A method can depend on the state (instance) variables in a class.  A free function outside of a class has no such dependence.

Example:

```
>>> x = "foo"
foo
>>> x.length()
3
```

The method length() has no arguments; however you can see it is dependent on the string's state (its character sequence).